# Determining the Associated Sequence If Sheffer Conditions are not Met

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

A sheffer sequence $s_n(x)$ is formed by considering the generating function

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty s_k(x)\frac{t^k}{k!}=A(t)e^{xB(t)}$$

where $A$ is an invertible power series, and $B$ is a delta series $(b_0=0, b_1\neq 0)$

Two power series $f, g$ uniquely determine these polynomials if the following condition is met;

$$\langle g(t)f(t)^k \mid s_n(x) \rangle=n!\delta_{n,k}$$

If $g(t)=1$, it is said that the polynomials are the associated sequence of $f(t)$.  Here, it is also necessary that $g$ be invertible and $f$ be a delta series.

Certainly, if the condition of the delta series is relaxed, we can still generate polynomial sequences.  From the looks of it, the major difference is that the index of the polynomial will be different from the power of the polynomial, a condition of Sheffer sequences.

Under this idea, if we let be $f$ be of order 2, $f(t)=a_2t^2+a_3t^3+...$, and we try and determine the "associated" polynomials, will they be unique?  I understand the definition of "associated" assumes $f$ is a delta series.  If they are unique, is there a quick way to generate them outside direct computation?

Comment: Just take your favorite symbolic math app and do a Taylor series expansion of your proposed e.g.f. Then inspect/explore the properties of the coefficients. Btw, look at https://oeis.org/A238363 for an example of a non-Sheffer sequence for which A(0)=0, B(t)=t, and the lowering op for the polynomials in the Taylor series expansion is d/dx, as for an Appell Sheffer sequence.